# ASP.NET File Download To Client With Cleanup On Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I think my question is similar to others asked, but just enough different that I won't get hammered for asking it.  I am copying an Excel file to a unique (user-specific) name, then opening the new file using Open XML SDK 2.0, changing some data, closing (saving) the user-specific file, then downloading it to the client.  My (old WebForms) code looks like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/Excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outputFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(Path.Combine(outputFolder, outputFile));
Response.End();
File.Delete(Path.Combine(outputFolder, outputFile));
```

As has been well documented in other questions, the Response.End() causes an exception and this prevents the File.Delete from ever being executed.  Interestingly, even if I handle the Response.End() exception, it keeps 'excepting' all the way back up through my calling code.  Any suggestions for getting the file on the server cleaned up?  I have tried some other suggestions that don't include Response.End(), but I get page data and other crazy stuff tailed on to my Excel file.

I had high hopes for the WebClient stuff in this article, but it downloaded to the server instead of the client:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2512241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like anything that requires the code to continue to execute after the response has been sent.  I would handle this 1 of 3 ways.

1. Find a way to make the changes entirely in memory without writing to a file.  I am not an Open XML expert, so I am not sure if this is possible with that SDK.
2. Read the file into memory.  Delete the file.  Return the contents.
3. Implement a temp folder with a cleanup job (Azure Web Jobs if Azure cloud hosted) that only deletes things that are older than N seconds old.

Comment: #1 is not possible with Open XML SDK.  I was also thinking about attempting #2 so, with your seconding of that motion, I will do just that.  I was trying to avoid #3 because I don't like things that rely on timing.